# multiple errors auth0 react apollo babel webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, auth0, apollo

I'm having a little bit of an issue when I want to implement auth0 on my project.
Whenever I solve one problem I run into another, it's always the same 3 errors :

> -require is not a function
>
> -window is not defined
>
> -missing class properties

I've tried solving it by playing with the babelrc, changing the order of the presets

And in webpack I've added the famous as below:

```
"plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'global.GENTLY': false })],"
```

in webpack to no avail

I'm providing the package json/ babelrc & web pack without the modifications I cited above so you can see the "base" without the failed attempts at fixing it
Also providing the screenshots with the errors

Thanks in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FogpD.jpg
for the errors

this is in babelrc

```
      {
      "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        ["@babel/preset-env", { "modules": false }],
        ["@babel/preset-stage-0", { "decoratorsLegacy": true }]
      ],
      "env": {
        "development": {
          "compact": false
        },
        "jest": {
          "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
        }
      },
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
        [
          "react-intl",
          {
            "messagesDir": "./extracted_messages/",
            "enforceDescriptions": true
          }
        ]
      ]
    }

and this is the webpack


const path = require('path')
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const distDir = path.join(__dirname, '../dist')
const srcDir = path.join(__dirname, '../src')

module.exports = [

  {
    name: 'client',
    target: 'web',
    mode: 'development',
    entry: `${srcDir}/client.jsx`,
    output: {
      path: distDir,
      filename: 'client.js',
      publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
      alias: {
        config: path.join(__dirname, '../config'),
        utils: path.join(__dirname, '../src/utils'),
        toolbox: path.join(__dirname, '../src/components/toolbox')
      }
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules\/)/,
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          query: { name: 'assets/images/[name].[ext]' }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          query: { name: 'assets/fonts/[name].[ext]' }
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'global.GENTLY': false }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'styles.css'
      }),
      new CopyPlugin([{ from: `${srcDir}/favicon.ico`, to: distDir }])]
  },
  {
    name: 'server',
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'development',
    entry: `${srcDir}/server.jsx`,
    output: {
      path: distDir,
      filename: 'server.js',
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
      publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
      alias: {
        config: path.join(__dirname, '../config'),
        utils: path.join(__dirname, '../src/utils'),
        toolbox: path.join(__dirname, '../src/components/toolbox'),
        inherits: 'inherits/inherits_browser.js',
        superagent: 'superagent/lib/client',
        emitter: 'component-emitter',
      }
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules\/)/,
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'isomorphic-style-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          query: { name: 'assets/images/[name].[ext]' }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          query: { name: 'assets/fonts/[name].[ext]' }
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'global.GENTLY': false }),
      new CopyPlugin([{ from: `${srcDir}/favicon.ico`, to: distDir }])]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem while writing for our blog. Our suggested fix is this;

```
function whatYouRunOnPageLoad() {
    if (typeof window !== undefined) {
        auth0.parseHash(... etc ...)
    }
}
```

`parseHash` requires `window`, which does not exist as part of your render steps. Auth0.js cannot run from serverside, which is what is "accidentally" happening when you try to render it the way you are.

Comment: Hey so the thing is I'm ,never calling window , I think it's auth0 that wants to call window but it can't
So I'm not really sure where I'd have to put the window != undefined and what I'd have to do it in it

Comment: Can you supply a link to your repo?

Comment: Can't do that, the repository is private :/

Comment: From my Gatsby example, I had to wrap our `this.auth0.parseHash` in `typeof window !== undefined`. While you might not directly be using it, that method will.

Answer (score -1):

Window error solved by doing:

```
if(global.window){...}
```

and later on by just not calling the function I was using at inappropriate times.

Require is not a function solved with:

```
[new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'global.GENTLY': false })]
```

in the webpack config at plugins (dev AND prod, idk why) + importing it with require and not import.

Webpack module error solved by changing the order of the presets in bablerc.

Comment: That solution is not as robust as what I suggested below. Auth0.js cannot be run in a render that occurs serverside. Our suggested solution is what I have suggested and it is probably better to both use and accept that solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please proofread and properly format your postings. Thanks!